# Solution fails to converge with different collocation point selection

Tags: convergence, collocation

I'm trying to learn about collocation. As an example, I am using Numerical Recipes, 20.7.12, but changing the basis. To wit, I'm trying to solve

$$y'' + y' - 2y + 2 = 0, -1 \le x \le 1, y(-1) = y(1) = 0$$

which has exact solution $y(x) = 1 - \frac{e^{x} \sinh(2) + e^{-2x}\sinh(1)}{\sinh(3)}$.
Now, Numerical Recipes is using the Chebyshev basis, but just to generate some understanding of the method I tried to use the following basis:

$$y(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}(x+1)\right)$$

The collocation method becomes

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \left[\left(2 + \frac{n^2\pi^2}{4} \right) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}(x_m+1) \right) - \frac{n\pi}{2} \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}(x_m+1) \right)\right]a_n = 2$$

where we choose $N$ points for $x_m$.

My understanding was that I had lots of freedom to choose $x_m$. So for example, I could choose $x_m = -1.0 + 2(m-1)/(N-1)$, or $x_m \sim \mathrm{unif}(-1,1)$, or $x_m = \cos(\frac{2m-1)\pi}{2N})$ (the Chebyshev nodes). The only thing to worry about was convergence rate or conditioning of the resulting matrix.

Is this belief correct? In the following code, uniformly spaced nodes converge (albeit slowly) but choosing the Chebyshev nodes for the collocation points appear to diverge!

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Plots
Plots.GRBackend()

function exact(x::Float64)
    return 1 - (exp(x)*sinh(2.0) + exp(-2*x)*sinh(1.0))/sinh(3.0)
end

function approximate(x::Float64, v::Vector{Float64})
    y = 0.0
    for n in 1:length(v)
        k = n*π/2
        y += v[n]*sin(k*(x+1))
    end
    return y
end

function ode(N::Int64)
    if N < 2
      error("N >= 2 is required.")
    end
    M = Matrix{Float64}(undef, N, N)
    for m in 1:N
      #=Uncomment and the solution will diverge!=#
      #=arg = cos((2*m-1)*π/(2.0*N))=#
      arg = -1.0 + 2.0*(m-1)/(N-1)
      for n in 1:N
        M[m,n] = (2+n*n*π*π/4)*sin(n*π*(arg+1)/2) - n*π*cos(n*π*(arg+1)/2)/2
      end
    end

    c = cond(M,1)
    println("Condition number of matrix is $c")
    B = lu(M)
    b  = Vector{Float64}(undef, N)
    for n in 1:N
      b[n] = 2.0
    end
    v = B\b
    p = plot([exact, x -> approximate(x, v)], xlims=(-1.0, 1.0))
    savefig(p, "solution.png")
end
```

Now, if you run this code you'll see that the condition number is worse for the Chebyshev nodes at a given $N$ than for the uniformly spaced nodes. However, I'm not sure that's a sufficient explanation, because even before the condition number renders to solve worthless, then collocation fails to converge.

Comment: In principle you've understood it correctly. In this case, I think you've incidentally chosen an unsuitable combination of basis and collocation points. Your problem only allows for odd functions as solutions, while the cosine is an  even function. I guess this leads to a zero eigenvalue in your system matrix, and thus to the divergence.

Comment: The basis doesn't only allow odd functions-the sine functions are shifted to avoid that. There is no zero eigenvalue in the matrix as can be seen from the computation of the condition number.

Comment: ah right, the y' term destroys the parity, so forget that. Then the reason is problably, that the minimal spacing of Chebyshev nodes is $1/\Delta x^2$ (whereas for uniform grid it is $1/\Delta x$), which in my experience quickly leads to ill-conditiones matrices.

Comment: Right. The question at hand though is that even when the condition number is perfectly fine to solve the linear system in double precision, the Chebyshev nodes lead to a solution which diverges from the reference solution.